# matplotlib viewer not displaying when I run code

Tags: python, matplotlib, random

I am very new to Python and am trying to work my way through the introductory book "Python Crash Course". I am working on one of the projects which is to model a random walk in matplotlib. However, I cannot get the viewer to display when I run the file "Data_Vis.py". This file imports the class RandomWalk from the file "random_walk.py". I am able to run both files with zero errors, but as I said I would expect to see a graphing generated. Thanks in advance for any help!!!

**"Data_Vis.py"**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import RandomWalk

rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()

plt.scatter(rw.x_values,rw.y_values,s=15)
plt.show()
```

---

**"random_walk.py"**

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk():

    def __init__(self,num_points=100):
        self.num_points = num_points

        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

    def fill_walk(self):


        while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
            x_direction = choice([-1,1])
            x_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance

            y_direction = choice([-1,1])
            y_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue

                next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
                next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

                self.x_values.append(next_x)
                self.y_values.append(next_y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I've edited your question so that the code is readable, but you'll have to edit your question as well.  As it stands, right now we're lacking in information.  You've told us what you expect, but you'll need to tell us more.  What results are you getting from your code?  Are you certain that any of your functions are running (you can test that easily simply by putting `print("1")` in different places in your code, preferably with different numbers in the different places.

Comment: When I copied the code directly as shown, it got stuck in an infinite loop, because `next_x =` etc are all indented at the `if/continue` level.  The code is unreachable and never executes.  Since you end up not appending to x_values, your while loop never finishes executing.  When I remove the indent, it properly shows a scatter plot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "due to a simple typo".  Fix your spacing, and you're ok.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much @ScottMermelstein! I got it to display